# Python Pandas in Sage Math 9.0 (Jupyter) - Windows

Tags: python, pandas, windows, jupyter, sage

I've just installed Sage Math 9.0 on Windows and it comes with a jupyter environment.
I do have Python installed on my PC and from within the command line i can use python and pandas.
But from the jupyter that came with SageMath i can not use pandas.

It looks like the jupyter that came with sage does not "know" from the "normal" python installation on my PC. Is there any way to get pandas working with the jupyter notebook from SageMath on Windows?

thanks a lot for every answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing on Windows you have three icons on the desktop: SageMath, SageMath Notebook, SageMath Shell.

Open the SageMath Shell and run this command:

```
pip install pandas
```

Then you can use Pandas in Sage's Python.