# SageMath 9.1 on Mac : install numpy / pandas

Tags: python, pandas, macos, jupyter-notebook, sage

is pandas (somewhat) compatible with SageMath ?
it seems so

[Python Pandas in Sage Math 9.0 (Jupyter) - Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078461/python-pandas-in-sage-math-9-0-jupyter-windows)

I would like to install pandas but on my Mac OS (I'm running SageMath 9.1 on Catalina 10.15.5)

I don't see any SageMath shell
all i have is a SageMath icon in the Applications folder which i double click to start SageMath.

Then it looks like a Jupyter environment.

[There is a menu in Jupyter, so that if i open a new notebook, i can choose between a Python 3 or a Sage notebook. Pandas is successfully installed when I open a Python 3 notebook]

Answer (score 1):

SageMath already ships NumPy so

```py
import numpy
```

should work without any extra work.

Using Pandas requires it being installed for Sage's Python;
it is not by default, but that can be achieved by running
one of the following pip invocations in a Jupyter notebook.

Either using the `%pip` IPython line magic:

```
%pip install pandas
```

Or using `!` to run a shell command from a Jupyter notebook cell:

```
!pip install pandas
```

Then restart the kernel and importing Pandas should now work:

```py
import pandas
```

This works seamlessly using the modern Sage macOS app from

- https://github.com/3-manifolds/Sage_macOS/releases

In older Sage versions on macOS, the `pip` command might
fail, complaining about TLS/SSL. Either upgrade to a more
recent Sage (see link above) or fix your Sage installation
using the appropriate `fix_mac_sage` from

- https://github.com/3-manifolds/fix_mac_sage/releases

that is, download e.g. the file `fix_mac_sage9_2.tgz`,
extract it, and follow the README.

This step was necessary in Sage <= 9.2 because macOS
does not ship OpenSSL, and Sage <= 9.2 could not ship it
either for unfortunate licensing reasons (now resolved).

Comment: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pandas
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pandas/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pandas
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Comment: i get the following above

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @TerrenceJ -- can you say which version of Sage you are using and how it was installed?

Comment: @SamuelLelièvre. - yes I am using sage 9.1 installed from here: http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/sage/osx/intel/old/index.html - the one ending in app.dmg if I remember correctly.

Comment: Try the new app: https://github.com/3-manifolds/Sage_macOS/releases

Comment: Hi @SamuelLelièvre , this is a while later, but I installed the version from the link you provided above, and it is all working very nicely! Many thanks for your help!